# Why PostGIS GIST index is not used?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, explain, gist-index

I am using PostGIS 2.2.1 with PostgreSQL 9.5.10. I have a table with a geography field for coordinates and I am making a simple bounding box query. The table has 1029 rows. `EXPLAIN` says it does a sequential scan. What is going on?

```
masa=# \d+ store
                                                          Table "public.store"
  Column   |          Type          |                      Modifiers                      | Storage  | Stats target |    Description     
-----------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+--------------------
 id        | integer                | not null default nextval('store_id_seq1'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 parent_id | integer                |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 name      | character varying(255) | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 coords    | geography(Point,4326)  |                                                     | main     |              | (DC2Type:geopoint)
Indexes:
    "store_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "uniq_ff5758775e237e06" UNIQUE, btree (name)
    "idx_ff575877727aca70" btree (parent_id)
    "idx_ff575877d86de985" gist (coords)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_ff575877727aca70" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES store(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "store_product" CONSTRAINT "fk_ca42254ab092a811" FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "store" CONSTRAINT "fk_ff575877727aca70" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES store(id)

masa=# explain SELECT * FROM store WHERE coords && ST_MakeEnvelope(24.93522187393,60.155284015594,24.95327552607,60.164258984406, 4326);
                                                                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on store  (cost=0.00..27.86 rows=206 width=58)
   Filter: (coords && '0103000020E610000001000000050000007F0863B36AEF3840AD48BC58E0134E407F0863B36AEF3840890C3B7006154E40408C68DD09F43840890C3B7006154E40408C68DD09F43840AD48BC58E0134E407F0863B36AEF3840AD48BC58E0134E40'::geography)
(2 rows)

masa=#
```

Apparently the reason was that table needed vacuum/analyze

```
masa=# VACUUM FULL ANALYZE store;
VACUUM
masa=# explain SELECT * FROM store WHERE coords && ST_MakeEnvelope(24.93522187393,60.155284015594,24.95327552607,60.164258984406, 4326);
                                                                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using idx_ff575877d86de985 on store  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=82)
   Index Cond: (coords && '0103000020E610000001000000050000007F0863B36AEF3840AD48BC58E0134E407F0863B36AEF3840890C3B7006154E40408C68DD09F43840890C3B7006154E40408C68DD09F43840AD48BC58E0134E407F0863B36AEF3840AD48BC58E0134E40'::geography)
(2 rows)

masa=#
```

Comment: what version of PostGIS and PostgreSQL?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it there. According to my installed packages it seems to be PostGIS 2.2.1 and PostgreSQL 9.5.10

Comment: Ok, first run `VACUUM ANALYZE FULL store;` then rerun your query with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: It solved this problem, but if you remember you suggested using `geography_overlaps()` in one of my questions and if I use it, it does not use the index. Why?

Comment: No, I explain it thoroughly even saying that `geography_overlaps` doesn't use an index, and I suggest using `ST_Intersects` which uses both a bounding box and actually tests for intersection with a spatial backend. check it out again, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191669/2639

Comment: The `ANALYZE` updates the stats for the index. If that solved the problem, then the problem was just you had stale statistics.

Comment: OK I assumed `geography_overlaps` would use index because you said `&&` literally calls it. But I missed what you meant by the "catch" about `&&` using index, meant `geaometry_overlaps` does not use index. I should stop doing this kind of stuff at 3AM :) If you put an answer, I can select is as correct. Although it is now self answered also :)

Comment: Pointer: Read Regina Obe's book PostGIS in Action. She's a bad ass. If you need a paid consultant I'm glad to help out too. Contact info in profile.

Comment: Do you have anything else you're looking to get out of this question?

Comment: Sorry, I had to go to sleep :) Everything is perfect for now...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Evan Carrol I figured I simply needed to run `# VACUUM FULL ANALYZE store;` on my table (which was named `store`) and then database started using the index on queries.